# Make game/site fit on screen without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have created a Erase-A-Man game and when i view it on a mobile device which is the main point. There is always scrolling to see the rest of the letters, I am trying to make the page fit all phone screen sizes so that there is no need to scroll up or down to see the whole game.  Any help would be grateful.

HTML

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
<p>

    <p id="warning">JavaScript must be enabled to play this game.</p>

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p>
  <div id="help"></div>
  <div id="helptext">
      <h2>How to Play</h2>
      <div id="close"></div>
        <p>Hangman is a word-guessing game. Click or tap New Game to display the letters of the alphabet and a row of dashes indicating the number of letters to be guessed. Click or tap a letter. If it's in the word, it replaces the dash(es). Each wrong guess results in a stroke being added to a gallows and its victim. Your role is to guess the word correctly before the victim meets his grisly fate.</p>
  </div>
  </p>
  </div>

  <p id="loading">Game loading. . .</p>

  <canvas id="stage" width="200" height="200">Sorry, your browser needs to       support canvas for this game.</canvas>

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p><div id="play">New Game</div> <div id="clear">Clear Score</div></p>
  </div>

  <p id="word"></p>

  <div id="letters"></div>

  <!--<div align="center"><img src="images/cactus-sslandscape_00152016.jpg"                              class="bg"></div> -->   

</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Javascript

```
// Global variables
var canvas = document.getElementById('stage'),
word = document.getElementById('word'),
letters = document.getElementById('letters'),
wordToGuess,
wordLength,
badGuesses,
correctGuesses;

function init() {
var helptext = $('#helptext'),
    w = screen.availWidth <= 800 ? screen.availWidth : 800;

// Hide the loading message and display the control buttons
$('#loading').hide();
$('#play').css('display', 'inline-block').click(newGame);
$('#clear').css('display', 'inline-block').click(resetScore);
$('#help').click(function(e) {
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    helptext.show().css('margin-left', (w-300)/2 + 'px');
});
$('#close').click(function(e) {
    $('#mask').remove();
    helptext.hide();
});

// Rescale the canvas if the screen is wider than 700px
if (screen.innerWidth >= 700) {
    canvas.getContext('2d').scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
// Initialize the scores and store locally if not already stored
if (localStorage.getItem('hangmanWin') == null) {
    localStorage.setItem('hangmanWin', '0');
} 
if (localStorage.getItem('hangmanLose') == null) {
    localStorage.setItem('hangmanLose', '0');
}
showScore();
}

// Display the score in the canvas
function showScore() {
var won = localStorage.getItem('hangmanWin'),
    lost = localStorage.getItem('hangmanLose'),
    c = canvas.getContext('2d');
// clear the canvas
canvas.width = canvas.width;
c.font = 'bold 24px stencil, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
c.fillStyle = 'black';
c.textAlign = 'center';
c.fillText('YOUR SCORE', 100, 50);
c.font = 'bold 18px Optimer, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
c.fillText('Won: ' + won + ' Lost: ' + lost, 100, 80);
}


// Start new game
function newGame() {
var placeholders = '',
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    abc =         ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'    ,'U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
badGuesses = 0;
correctGuesses = 0;
wordToGuess = getWord();
wordLength = wordToGuess.length;
// create row of underscores the same length as letters to guess
for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    placeholders += '_';
}
word.innerHTML = placeholders;
// create an alphabet pad to select letters
letters.innerHTML = '';
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    div.innerHTML = abc[i];
    div.onclick = getLetter;
    frag.appendChild(div);
}
letters.appendChild(frag);
drawCanvas();
}

// Get selected letter and remove it from the alphabet pad
function getLetter() {
checkLetter(this.innerHTML);
this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
this.style.cursor = 'default';
this.onclick = null;
}

// Check whether selected letter is in the word to be guessed
function checkLetter(letter) {
var placeholders = word.innerHTML,
    wrongGuess = true;
// split the placeholders into an array
placeholders = placeholders.split('');
// loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    // if the selected letter matches one in the word to guess,
    // replace the underscore and increase the number of correct guesses
    if (wordToGuess.charAt(i) == letter.toLowerCase()) {
        placeholders[i] = letter;
        wrongGuess = false;
        correctGuesses++;
        // redraw the canvas only if all letters have been guessed
        if (correctGuesses == wordLength) {
            drawCanvas();
        }
    }
}
// if the guess was incorrect, increment the number of bad
// guesses and redraw the canvas
if (wrongGuess) {
    badGuesses++;
    drawCanvas();
}
// convert the array to a string and display it again
word.innerHTML = placeholders.join('');
}

// Draw the canvas
function drawCanvas() {
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
// reset the canvas and set basic styles
canvas.width = canvas.width;
c.lineWidth = 3;
c.strokeStyle = 'green';
c.font = 'bold 24px Optimer, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
c.fillStyle = 'red';
// draw the ground
drawLine(c, [20,172], [180,172]);
c.strokeStyle = 'black';
// draw head
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(115, 45);
        c.arc(100, 45, 15, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360);
        c.stroke();
// draw Left eye
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(97, 39);
        c.arc(95, 40, 2, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360);
        c.stroke();
// draw right eye
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(103, 39);
        c.arc(105, 40, 2, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360);
        c.stroke();
// draw mouth
        drawLine(c, [92,53], [108,50]);
// draw body
        drawLine(c, [100,60], [100,130]); 
// draw left arm
        drawLine(c, [100,80], [65,90]);
// draw right arm
        drawLine(c, [100,80], [135,90]);
// draw left leg
        drawLine(c, [100,130], [85,170]);
// draw right leg and end game
        drawLine(c, [100,130], [115,170]);

// start building the gallows if there's been a bad guess
if (badGuesses > 0) {
    // erase the right arm
    c.lineWidth = 6;
    c.strokeStyle = '#E6E6E6';
        drawLine(c, [100,80], [135,90]);
    if (badGuesses > 1) {
        // Erase left leg
        drawLine(c, [100,130], [85,170]);
    }
    if (badGuesses > 2) {
        // Erase left arm
        drawLine(c, [100,80], [65,90]);
    }
    if (badGuesses > 3) {
        // Erase right leg
        drawLine(c, [100,130], [115,170]);
    }
    if (badGuesses > 4) {
        // Erase body
        drawLine(c, [100,60], [100,130]);
    }
    if (badGuesses > 5) {
        // Erase mouth
        drawLine(c, [92,53], [108,50]);
    }
    if (badGuesses > 6) {
        // Erase head
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(115, 45);
        c.arc(100, 45, 15, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360);
        c.stroke();
    }
    if (badGuesses > 7) {
        // Erase Right eye
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(103, 39);
        c.arc(105, 40, 2, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360);
        c.stroke();
    }
    if (badGuesses > 8) {
        //Erase Left eye
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(97, 39);
        c.arc(95, 40, 2, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360);
        c.stroke();
        c.fillText('Game over', 45, 110);
        // remove the alphabet pad
        letters.innerHTML = '';
        // display the correct answer
        // need to use setTimeout to prevent race condition
        setTimeout(showResult, 200);
        // increase score of lost games
        localStorage.setItem('hangmanLose', 1 +     parseInt(localStorage.getItem('hangmanLose')));
        // display the score after two seconds
        setTimeout(showScore, 2000);
    }
}
// if the word has been guessed correctly, display message,
// update score of games won, and then show score after 2 seconds
if (correctGuesses == wordLength) {
    letters.innerHTML = '';
    c.fillText('You won!', 45,110);
    // increase score of won games
    // display score
    localStorage.setItem('hangmanWin', 1 +    parseInt(localStorage.getItem('hangmanWin')));
    setTimeout(showScore, 2000);
}
}

function drawLine(context, from, to) {
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(from[0], from[1]);
context.lineTo(to[0], to[1]);
context.stroke();
}

// When the game is over, display missing letters in red
function showResult() {
var placeholders = word.innerHTML;
placeholders = placeholders.split('');
for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    if (placeholders[i] == '_') {
        placeholders[i] = '<span style="color:red">' +      wordToGuess.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + '</span>';
    }
}
word.innerHTML = placeholders.join('');
}

// Reset stored scores to zero
function resetScore() {
localStorage.setItem('hangmanWin', '0');
localStorage.setItem('hangmanLose', '0');
showScore();
}

// Select random word to guess
function getWord() {
var a = new      Array('a','we','you','will','he','to','bed','ton','tin','tan','can','see','run', 'the','in','so','no','now','man','ten','me','do','and','go','at','on','a','it','is','she');
return a[parseInt(Math.random()* a.length)];
}
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

should be doable with CSS.

```
#home {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively you can set the property with javascript.

```
document.getElementById('home').style.overflow = hidden;
```

I havent used jquery before, but i know its possible to set element properties with it, so you might want to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the tags holding the letters into `<span>`s if you don't want the letters to go off the bottom of the screen.

Just change:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

to

```
var div = document.createElement('span');
```